# When was the first action sequence involving a parachuteless jump out of a plane filmed?

Tags: first-appearance, stunts

The 1991 movie *Point Break* features a sequence where Special Agent Johnny Utah jumps out of a plane without a parachute and catches up to another person with a chute while in mid-air.

I believe I've since seen variations on this idea since then as well as other action sequences involving similar moves.

Is *Point Break* the first appearance of such a sequence? Or had it been done previously?

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I was curious about at what point it actually became technically feasible to do it. Cameras that would work for movie level capture in those circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this documentary](https://youtube.com/watch?v=c2dJydTEL-s), this was first done 12 years earlier than Point Break in the 1979 James Bond film [Moonraker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonraker_(film)).